# How to branch a forked repo in GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I have forked the repo but it is not allowing me to edit the code because i have not 'branched' it.
Any solutions?

Comment: That makes no sense: whichever branch you're on in your fork is independent of the same-named branch in the original. Are you definitely trying to edit your own fork?

Comment: But if you need to make a branch you can do it from the branch dropdown on the web UI. Or are you trying to edit a local cloned copy?

Comment: Ya, i want to make edits to a locally forked copy, is that possible?

Comment: When you say "locally forked copy" you mean you forked the repo on GitHub then you went to the fork on the web interface and then clicked the 'code' button to get the URL so you could make a clone on your computer? Yes, you can edit any version of the repo you have on your computer whether it's using the original or fork as its upstream origin remote. GitHub has no way of stopping you editing files you have locally. Unless you're using some unusual Git client that would enforce this, I suppose. Are you using a specific GUI for Git, or just the command-line version?

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed explanation. But i only forked the repositary to my own as in the repo shows up in mine. I have not saved it locally to my pc.